# Is there a verb meaning to wet the floor or spread water on the area by drips or droplets?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, idioms

Like when you are out and got wet in the rain, you run inside and spread water around. Or when you finished showering and you rush to get your towel because you forgot keep near the shower for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's the obvious one:  you use ***drip*** as a noun in your question title ("by drips or droplets"), but it can also be used as a transitive verb.

> Coming inside from the storm, I *dripped* water all over the floor.
>
> My towel wasn't on the rack by the shower, so I *dripped* water on the bathroom floor as I went to get a new one from the closet.

Comment: Good idea, but it's not a "noun" - "dripped" is being used as a verb.

Comment: @WS2: I'm confused.  Doesn't the question ask for a verb?  I wanted to make sure that the questioner knew that "drip" could also be used as a verb, not just as a noun as they use it in the question title ("by drips or droplets".)

Comment: Apologies, I seem to have misunderstood your answer first time.

Answer (score 0):

**Splatter** is a more active version than drip or dribble, suggests the water getting on the walls as well and implies more liquid being involved. Think of a dog shaking itself after a bath. Rushing around after a shower would splatter water everywhere, though not as much as a shaggy dog would do!

Answer (score -2):

'to pool around'; as in water pooled around  the table leg'

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Pooling wouldn't apply to the way in which water is distributed according to the question